# C# LINQ join Datatables show data if not null

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have 2 datatables. I have joined the Datatables via LINQ query

```
var rows = wdt.AsEnumerable().Join(
                    mdt.AsEnumerable(),
                    wdtRows => wdtRows.Field<int?>("userID1"),
                    (wdtRows, mdtRows1) => new { wdtRows, mdtRows1 }
                    ) //New anon<datarow,datarow> - I will call anons 'n' (for new) below
                    .Join(
                    mdt.AsEnumerable(),
                    n => n.wdtRows.Field<int?>("userID2"),
                    mdtRows2 => mdtRows2.Field<int>("iD"),
                    (n, mdtRows2) => new { n.wdtRows, n.mdtRows1, mdtRows2 }
                    )//New anon<datarow,datarow,datarow>
                    .Join(
                    mdt.AsEnumerable(),
                    n => n.wdtRows.Field<int?>("userID3"),
                    mdtRows3 => mdtRows3.Field<int>("iD"),
                    (n, mdtRows3) => new { n.wdtRows, n.mdtRows1, n.mdtRows2, mdtRows3 }
                    ) //New anon<datarow,datarow,datarow,datarow> - all joined up now
                    .ToList();

                rows.ForEach(r =>
                {
                    var datarow = dt.NewRow();
                    datarow[0] = r.mdtRows1.Field<string>("firstName") + " " + r.mdtRows1.Field<string>("lastName");
                    datarow[1] = r.mdtRows2.Field<string>("firstName") + " " + r.mdtRows2.Field<string>("lastName");
                    datarow[2] = r.mdtRows3.Field<string>("firstName") + " " + r.mdtRows3.Field<string>("lastName");
                    datarow[3] = r.wdtRows[3].ToString();

                    //If you can find a way to add a range (or turn a List<datarow> into a table)
                    //this you can change this section to a select and return the datarow instead
                    dt.Rows.Add(datarow);
```

Above query is working fine. But i want changes in the above code. While joining the Datatables, i want if `n.wdtRows["userID2"]` is null or 0, then it should show data of the row, but currently it shows no data of other users i.e. userID1 & userID3.

Datatable1 :

```
iD  firstname  lastname
1      b           v
2      d           c
3      f           g
4      s           o
```

....

Datatable2 :

```
Code        userid1    userid2      userid3  work
    1f           1           3           6       gg
    2g           1           4           7       gg
    3b           3           4           7       gg
    4v           4           3           8       gg
```

New Datatable :

```
Code    username1   username2   username3  work
1f           a           b           c       gg
2g           d           f           r       gg
3b           c           h           g       gg
4v           d           s           h       gg
```

Comment: pretty hard to make out what you are trying to achive... there should be strongly typed datarows (assuming you used the designer to define your datatables) that will simplify this task considerably

Comment: Method syntax is really hard to understand when it comes to joins. For that reason i always split  a query into multiples, the join part as query  and the rest with method syntax. It's as efficient since Join is executed deferred.

Comment: As an aside, instead of converting an `int`-field to `string` and parsing that to `int` use `row.Field<int>("ColumnName")` instead.  `Field`   supports also nullable-types. So it's simple as: `int? userID2 = n.wdtRows.Field<int?>("userID2")`. This is much  more readable and efficicient as: `Convert.ToInt32(string.IsNullOrEmpty(n.wdtRows["userID2"].ToString()) ? 0 : n.wdtRows["userID2"])`.

Comment: You need to flatten Datatable2 to: Code, ID, work before joining with Datatable1.